# Keras UNET implementation predicts very bad

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am new to Deep Learning, but I want to become a profi. Seems, like without external guidance it's hard to do :-)

I am trying to adopt this approach https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azM57JuQpQI&t=23s which is based on this article https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/unet-keras-segmenting-images/ to my task of satellite image segmentation using UNET with Keras.

Here's my code for training the network

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import random
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import cv2
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau

from skimage.io import imread, imshow
from skimage.transform import resize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'tensorflow'

seed = 42
np.random.seed = seed

IMAGE_HEIGHT = 256
IMAGE_WIDTH = 256
IMAGE_CHANELS = 3

trainImageFolderPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Bright Dunes Groups')

train_ids = next(os.walk(trainImageFolderPath))[1]

X_train = np.zeros((len(train_ids), IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_CHANELS), dtype=np.uint8)
Y_train = np.zeros((len(train_ids), IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 1), dtype=np.bool)

print('Building training set...')

for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(train_ids), total=len(train_ids)):
    path = os.path.join(trainImageFolderPath, id_)
    imagePath = os.path.join(path, id_ + '.jpg')
    img = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    img = resize(img, (IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH), mode='constant', preserve_range=True)

    X_train[n] = img

    mask = np.zeros((IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 1), dtype=np.bool)

    for mask_file in next(os.walk(os.path.join(path, 'masks')))[2]:
        maskPath = os.path.join(path, 'masks', mask_file)
        mask_ = cv2.imread(maskPath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        mask_ = resize(mask_, (IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH), mode='constant', preserve_range=True)

        mask_ = np.expand_dims(mask_, axis=-1)
        mask = np.maximum(mask, mask_)

    Y_train[n] = mask

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_CHANELS))

s = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x/255)(inputs)

c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(s)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c1)
p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c1)

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p1)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c2)
p2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c2)

c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p2)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c3)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c3)
p3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c3)

c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p3)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c4)
p4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))(c4)

c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p4)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c5)

u6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(c5)
u6 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c6)

u7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(c6)
u7 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c7)

u8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(c7)
u8 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c8)

u9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(c8)
u9 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c9)

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (1,1), activation='sigmoid')(c9)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()


######################################################################################################
callbacks = [
    EarlyStopping(patience=5, verbose=1),
    ReduceLROnPlateau(factor=0.2, patience=3, min_lr=0.001, verbose=1),
    ModelCheckpoint('bright_Dunes_Groups_model.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
]
######################################################################################################


results = model.fit(X_train, 
                    Y_train,
                    validation_split=0.25,
                    batch_size=16,
                    epochs=80,
                    callbacks = callbacks)

###############################################################
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.title("Learning curve")
plt.plot(results.history["loss"], label="loss")
plt.plot(results.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss")
plt.plot( np.argmin(results.history["val_loss"]), np.min(results.history["val_loss"]), marker="x", color="r", label="best model")
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylabel("log_loss")
plt.legend()
###############################################################

idx = random.randint(0, len(X_train))

predictions_train = model.predict(X_train[:int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9)], verbose=1)
predictions_value = model.predict(X_train[int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9):], verbose=1)

predictions_train_t = (predictions_train > 0.5).astype(np.uint8)
predictions_value_t = (predictions_value > 0.5).astype(np.uint8)

###### random training sample

ix = random.randint(0, len(predictions_train_t))
imshow(X_train[ix])
plt.show()
imshow(np.squeeze(Y_train[ix]))
plt.show()
imshow(np.squeeze(predictions_train_t[ix]))
plt.show()

###### random validation sample
ix = random.randint(0, len(predictions_value_t))
imshow(X_train[int(X_train.shape[0]*0.9):][ix])
plt.show()
imshow(np.squeeze(Y_train[int(Y_train.shape[0]*0.9):][ix]))
plt.show()
imshow(np.squeeze(predictions_value_t[ix]))
plt.show()
```

My trainig dataset consists of 141 images (X_train) and set of masks for each of them. I know, it's a small amount of data, but I would expect at least something even from this dataset. 
Accuracy is aboout 75%, but when I try to test it with the code below, I gives me very bad results.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import random
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import cv2

from skimage.io import imread, imshow
from skimage.transform import resize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'tensorflow'

IMAGE_HEIGHT = 256
IMAGE_WIDTH = 256
IMAGE_CHANELS = 3

modelFilePath = 'bright_Dunes_Groups_model.h5'
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(modelFilePath)

testImageFolderPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'TestDunes')

test_ids = next(os.walk(testImageFolderPath))[2]

for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(test_ids), total=len(test_ids)):
    imagePath = os.path.join(testImageFolderPath, id_)
    img = cv2.imread(imagePath)

    img = cv2.resize(img, (IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH))

    imshow(img)
    plt.show()

    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)

    predictions = model.predict(img, verbose=1)

    predictions_value_t = (predictions > 0.33).astype(np.uint8)
    imshow(np.squeeze(predictions_value_t))
    plt.show()
```

Predictions are very bad.

So, I suspect problem in at least 1 of 2 places:
1) in the code
2) in the dataset

One of the sample of my X_train is this

[X_train sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F9Af.jpg)

Corresponding mask looks like this

[Corresponding X_train mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Os8D.jpg)

Each X_train can have many masks, but for this particular image there's only one mask.

Each X_train image has dimensions 227*227 pixels. In the code I resize it (and mask) to 256*256

For each X_train image I perform data augmentation manually (I rotate X_train and corresponding mask 90, 180, 270 degrees and flip horizontaly and vertically). As I mentioned, all together augmented data gives me 141 X_train images.

One of the ways to check if problem is with dataset is to generate more X_train and masks. However the problem is that it's a manual process and very time-consuming operation. So, before doing this I want to know what else could be wrong with my solution.

What I also suspect as one of the source of the problems, that masks can have very different shape. Could it be, that non-homogenous shape of the mask create this bad prediction result?

Answer (score 2):

I see some starting point to (not solve, but) double-check your code/dataset. I am summarizing them below:

1. You are resizing the training data using the `skimage.transform.resize` but you are resizing the testing data using `cv2.resize`. I would be careful. Make sure both of them do the same. Some functions scale the range of values while resizing.
2. You have a lambda layer that is expected to rescale inputs in the range [0, 255] to the range of [0, 1]. Again, make sure that your preprocessing resize function does not already do this for you.
3. Usually, dividing by 255.0 is a good shortcut for rescaling input images to be in the range of [0, 1] and it works well for RGB images as the pixel values are in the range [0, 255], but please make sure your satellite images also have this range, otherwise this operation does not work as intended and you need to divide it by the maximum value in your own satellite images and not by 255.

Hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: Great points! Will check this and update the post with results. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I am not sure I understood point #2. For X_train I do not see in code where I convert range [0, 255] to [0,1]. Can you, please, clarify?
And point #3... Since my X_train images are grayscale (that means each image has different max pixel value) should I skip dividing the value of the image? Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

So, I followed suggestions of Bashir Kazimi and now I see significant improvement!

First of all, I must mention that images that I used for training were grayscale, not RGB as it was in the sample I tried to adopt. I think, this was the main reason for such inaccurate predictions.

What I did
1) replaced reading and resizing of openCV to skimage in both training and testing
2) removed for Lambda layer dividing of the input to 255.

For 2) I am not sure that I understood well what Bashir Kazimi suggested, but for now as  I understand there is no need in scaling X_train images to the range [0, 255] cause these images are already in this range. That's the only significant thing that I changed for now. Was there something else that was assumed, or not?

Now lambda layer looks like this

```
s = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x)(inputs)
```

Comment: sorry for not replying earlier. Actually I meant that you are assuming your inputs are in the range [0, 255] and you are using the lambda layer to divide by 255 in order to scale it to the range of [0, 1]. I was suggesting to double-check this and see if the resizing operations are already scaling your inputs to the range of [0,1] or not. Plus, if you're not  scaling, i.e., dividing by 255, you do not need the lambda layer. Just pass remove it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I already removed lambda layer, so I start directly from inputs. That didn't help me a lot. Now I am trying another implementation of the UNET for satellite images. They use BatchNormalizatio there. Will see if that will help.